# DIRECT WiFi-Ethernet bridge on linux

Tags: networking, debian, raspberry-pi

So, I have a particular situation: I have a Marantz AVR that doesn't have WiFi, and a raspberry pi 3 with wifi running raspbian right next to it. I tried looking for solutions, but they all create a second NAT, therefore blocking AirPlay, which is what I need. Does anyone have a solution that allows the device to be connected directly to the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not not possible to bridge a WLAN station (client) directly to LAN, because the default mode on WLAN is 3-address, which means there's no room for the extra MAC address needed to distinguish the WLAN station (RaspPi) from anything else behind the bridge (Marantz).

It's possible to bridge a WLAN access point, however.

It's also possible to bridge a WLAN in 4-address mode, but all of your WLAN stations must be capable of using that mode.

See e.g. `iw set 4addr`.